# TfIdf learning rate / document weight

Tags: machine-learning, tf-idf

I'm currently using sklearn to build an application that compares a given document with other documents, looking for similarity.

When using other techniques like LSA, I know that I can tune the learning rate so that older documents are forgot or less important. Is there some way for me to do something similar using TfIdf? It would be better if I could define a weight proportional to the "date" of a document.

I was thinking on applying some sort of slowly decaying exponential function on the relative date of the document, and multiplying this to the final cosine score of the similarity. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea. tfidf score is obtained with your entire document repository. If you want to "deprecate" the old terms, you should keep updating your document repository. For example:

```
each month, 
 * Remove the 5% oldest document in the repository.
 * Add 5% latest document to the repository.
```

This way, your tfidf score is automatically considering the "refreshness" of your data instead of using a set of magic parameters, for instance, how do you define the weight proportional to the "date" of a document.

This also achieves the same effect of decaying old data, since every 20 months you have an entirely new repository.

Comment: I'm doing something like ElasticSearch does: https://marcobonzanini.com/category/relevance/

Answer (score 0):

I found those articles that detail how ElasticSearch boosts search results based on, for example, date: https://marcobonzanini.com/category/relevance/

I'm doing something on these lines.